# Align word to right in latex

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I want to align just one word to the right margin.

When I try this command:

```
$A \implies B$ \begin{flushright} hipoteza \end{flushright}
```

Word aligns to the right, but in the next line.

[image]

When I try command:

```
$A \implies B$ \rightline{hipoteza}
```

Word is in the same line, but it's too much aligned to right.

[image]

Is there any way to fix this? I'm new to latex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\hfill`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

$A \implies B$ \hfill hipoteza


\end{document}
```

Comment: when I run command `$A \implies B$ \hfill [hipoteza 1]` it prints `[hipoteza1]` without space... do you know how to fix this? to print `[hipoteza 1]`

Comment: @codproe Works fine for me https://i.stack.imgur.com/Psuqp.png Can you ask a new question including a [mre] which allows us to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I found solution, I just need to add `\,` and space will be added, thank you very much

Comment: @codproe This might cure the symptoms, but does not solve the problem. I suspect you might be in math mode, but without code that's hard to diagnose. You should better fix this error. Chances are that also the wrong font is used and the kerning is messed up.